# Limitar número num input - 2ª dúvida

Tags: php, javascript, html

Meu objetivo num post anterior era colocar um valor máximo e mínimo em um campo de texto, um usuário solucionou ele quase perfeitamente. Vamos utilizar como exemplo no máximo o número `37`:

```js
function checa(e){
   const mi = +e.min;
   const ma = +e.max;
   const va = e.value;
   if(va < mi){
      e.value = mi;
   }else if(va > ma){
      e.value = ma;
   }
}
```

```html
<input oninput="checa(this)" value="1" type="number" min="1" max="37">
```

Porém, caso o número máximo for por exemplo `10`, ele não conseguirá apagar o número 1 para conseguir digitar por exemplo, um `7`. Mas o número mínimo tem que ser 1, alguém saberia como ampliar essa solução?

Segue o link do post antigo: [Limitar número num input](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/440115/limitar-n%c3%bamero-num-input)

Comment: Como ... Não entendi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No cenário do numero máximo ser 10, você pode alterar a função `checa` para permitir que o campo fique vazio, permitindo assim que o valor mínimo seja apagado e o valor 7 seja inserido:

```js
function checa(e){
   const mi = +e.min;
   const ma = +e.max;
   const va = e.value;

   if(va.length) {
      if(va < mi){
         e.value = mi;
      }else if(va > ma){
         e.value = ma;
      }
   }
}
```

```html
<input oninput="checa(this)" value="1" type="number" min="1" max="10">
```

---

Mas isso pode gerar um problema pra você, caso esse campo seja obrigatório!

Se o campo for obrigatório e estiver dentro de um `form`, você pode utilizar do atributo `required` no seu `input`:

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" min="1" max="10" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Veja que se você deixar o campo vazio, o *submit* não permite o envio.

---

Se seu campo não está dentro de um formulário e você precisa que ele tenha um valor, você pode implementar o evento `onblur` para que ao sair do campo, caso o mesmo esteja vazio, seja inserido um valor, podendo ser o valor mínimo:

```js
function checa(e){
    const mi = +e.min;
    const ma = +e.max;
    const va = e.value;

    if (va.length) {
        if(va < mi){
            e.value = mi;
        }else if(va > ma){
            e.value = ma;
        }
    }
}

function valorMinimo(e) {
    if (!e.value.length) {
        e.value = e.min;
    }
}
```

```html
<input oninput="checa(this)" onblur="valorMinimo(this)" value="1" type="number" min="1" max="10">
```

Comment: Se seu campo não está dentro de um formulário, ele está semanticamente incorreto, coloque dentro de um formulário. Nem faz sentido ter um `input` fora de um `form`

Comment: Funcionou aqui amigo. Ele está dentro de um formulário sim. Abraço!